# Preservation of local optima of submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization

Let $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function over a smooth manifold M, and $x^* \in M$ a local optimum of $\max_{x \in N} f(x)$, where N is a submanifold of M.

My question is: Under what conditions $x^*$ is a local optima of $\max_{x \in M} f(x)$ ?